# Error inflating class set in xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I'm trying to create a `textView` that slides up the screen and it creates an error, but I don't know why. This is my xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <scale
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_message"
        android:text="@string/scroll_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:maxLines="10"
        android:width="250dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</set>
```

And my activty class:

```
package com.example.rsa.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;  
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ScrollView;


public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
      //TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_message);
}


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_my, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The error given is:

```
            09-10 09:02:47.117  31292-31292/com.example.rsa.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.rsa.myapplication, PID: 31292
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.rsa.myapplication/com.example.rsa.myapplication.MyActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class set
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:143)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1258)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5070)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:836)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:631)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class set
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:753)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:478)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:410)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:361)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:350)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2122)
        at com.example.ranjeev.myapplication.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:23)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5720)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1102)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2208)
```

What would cause this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the animation set in code, like that:

```
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    textView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.slide_up));
}
```

Comment: Hi.....when I use this code it errors on `R.anim.slide_up`, saying 'Error: cannot find symbol variable `anim`

Comment: I assumed you saved your animation set in the `anim` resources folder as an xml file named `slide_up.xml`. You should really read the Android Developers guide for animations: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html

Comment: No the xml file called `activity_my` is in the layout folder. Creating an `anim` folder still shows the same error.